# Simple Carousel with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 3D Carousel using CSS3 (`transform`).

But, there is a problem.

Look at the pictures below:

[image]

The first image is result of my current code (which likes looking carousel from inside, also with bugs :P ), but I want to get something like second image. (looking like a carousel from outside, and bug free!)

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/1/) is my code.

**I can use negative values of degrees for this purpose; but if I do that, the height of left and right `div`s will be bigger than center `div`. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/upEC6/5/).**

How to get something like the second image? Which CSS Transform codes should I use?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/upEC6/2/) what you want??

Comment: In your example, The height of left and right `div`s are bigger than the height of center `div`...

Comment: updated demo with height fixed [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/upEC6/6/).. In order fix the height issue you need to give -ve translation along z-axis

Comment: What do you mean about -ve translation and so? Are you applied them in your demo?

Comment: yes [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/upEC6/6/)

Comment: I think you just increased `perspective` value. Am I thinking wrong? its height is still a little bit bigger.

Comment: just check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/upEC6/18/) actually i hav changed style only for webkit earlier

Comment: Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/upEC6/18/)** of what you want

**EDIT:**
In order to fix the height issue on applying the **negative transform rotate**, you need to give **-ve translation along z-axis** and also **-ve and +ve translation along X-axis** to left and right elements respectively.

EDIT:
well there are lot of tutorials explaining the use of css3 translation
I am pointing to one of those

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: It would be nice if you tell what you did to make my code work in answer. (for other people :P )

Comment: And, Can you explain about what do these functions do? (`translateX`, `translateY` and `translateZ`)

Comment: Translate means move, so `translateZ(-20px)`, moves the object 20 along the Z-axis, or 20px away from the screen in virtual 3d space.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to reverse the perspective angles; for a1 you needed `rotateY(-20)` and for c1 you needed `rotateY(20)`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/upEC6/4/

EDIT:

Seeing your comment; the height of the div is going to be larger because the edge of the div is virtually closer to you. If you want the divs to appear to be the exact same height, you need to reduce their initial height a few pixels, or increase the height of the center div to 'zoom' it, like the edges of the rotated divs are 'zoomed in'. When the rotation angle is reversed you don't notice the height difference because it is small.

EDIT:

In addition the far edges of the div slightly smaller than the closer edges; if your divs were long enough one edge would be the height of the screen and then other would be a tiny point.

Comment: After doing this, I want to animate this, and if I use different div heights, There will be many problems... Isn't there any other way to do this with same heights? I mean, I want one side of div be same distance of center div, and the other side more far from me.

Comment: I think if you were animating it with Javascript you could take the height difference into account with a little math, let me see if I can come up with something in a little bit.

Comment: (I want to animate it with CSS3 `transition`s and jQuery)

Comment: I think its OK if I set a little smaller height for `a` and `c` classes, and It will be fixed automatically while playing animation by CSS3 `transition`s. Am I thinking right?

Comment: I *think* if you multiplied the height of the center div by .05, add that height tot he center div, then used half the result for a negative top margin, it would look almost seemless (at least for 20 deg rotation)

Comment: OK. I'll play with numbers to make it as seamless as possible. Thanks!